# problem with jpa, persistence.xml, glassfish netbeans ide postgresql db pool an jdbc resource and jta

Tags: glassfish, pool, jta, persistence.xml

I'm running :
    so: linux ubuntu 17
    db: postgresql
    java 8
    netbeans ide 8

I'm triying a jpa application  in j2ee but with problem with the jta
    reference to my
          connection pool configured in glassfish

1. I've configured a pool name and jdbc resorce jndi name at 
   glassfish5, both of them are
    binded.

   > JDBC RESOURCE : jdbc/MYDB2B__pm
   >   DBC POOL associated : MYDB2Bpool
2. I've configured a persistence.xml in my mave proyect at /META-INF

   > `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   >   <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
   >       <persistence-unit name ="personaPU">
   >           <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDB2DB__pm</jta-data-source>
   >       </persistence-unit>
   >   </persistence>`

When I clean and build or run any test file I received the next message:

> Jun 29, 2019 9:05:12 PM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
>       SEVERE: Exception while invoking class 
>       org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/MyDB2DB__pm

Comment: I want to mentione that my project is a maven project.

Comment: I'm running :
    so: linux ubuntu 17
    db: postgresql
    java 8
    netbeans ide 8

    I'm triying a jpa application  in j2ee but with problem with the jta reference to my
          connection pool configured in glassfish

Comment: I want to mentione that if a I change the name to jdbc/MyDB2DB  I received the same problem with the added suffix

Comment: In Resume: configuring my glassfish admin console with a pool name MYDB2B which is binded with jdbc resource named jdbc/MYDB2B , having my persistence.xml configured via <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDB2DB</jta-data-source>, independent of the name I use in the <jta-data-source> I obtain an error whichs says: "Jun 29, 2019 9:05:12 PM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/MyDB2DB__pm", I don't Know where does the __pm suffix come